# Create my own Radio-like-button with a DIV?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a site where users can create there own social networking buttons. (I know its been done but its mostly for practice). A part of the site will allow users to choose the shape of the buttons. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="design" id="shape">
  <div class="shapeSelect square" id="square"></div>
  <div class="shapeSelect rounded" id="rounded"></div>
  <div class="shapeSelect circle" id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is add an event listener when the div is clicked. After it's clicked the class attribute would be changed to "selected." When another one would be click then the first clicked one would be cleared and the next one would be selected. Just like with radio buttons.

I am familiar with JavaScript and my idea was this:

```
    window.onload = function () {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById("square").addEventListener('click', function (e) {//adds the event listener
       divArray = document.getElementById("shape");//Here is my first issue: an array is not returned
       if (!(document.getElementById("square").getAttribute("class") == "shapeSelect square selected")) {// checks to make sure its not already selected
            for (i = 0, count = document.getElementById("shape").length; i < count; i++) {// if it isn't go through the array
                divArray[i]// and this is where i also get stuck. I Can't figure out how i would return the class attribute to be class="shapeSelect circle" instead of class="shapeSelect circle selected"
            };
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: And why not use radio buttons?

Comment: @BramVanroy radio buttons are ugly :(

Comment: @aaronman Most irrelevant answer I could have expected. You can't trick screenreaders or mobile devices into thinking a regular div is a radio button. Also, here are some styling tips: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: Radio Buttons are ugly as aaronman said and the user will have a hard time visualizing what it will look like if the text just says rounded square or circle

Comment: @BramVanroy it's funny that you were obnoxious and wrong at the same time

Comment: @aaronman It's funny that I am not. The argument of something not being beautiful is only relevant as long as it does not cause practical problems, as is the case here. Just styling a div to resemble a radio button is *very* bad practice, as I have mentioned before.

Comment: @BramVanroy I said nothing about divs, radio buttons have an unapealling look most ui frameworks replace them with a different element. Also none of this changes this fact that you felt the need to call my comment(not an answer) irrelevant when it was actually the exact problem the OP is having

Comment: @BramVanroy I checked and most UI frameworks use normal buttons (which are easier to style) and manage the rest on their own with JS

Comment: @aaronman Alright, I was too harsh, I'm sorry about that. Nonetheless, I still don't agree that one should use a specific element because it is easier to style when you defile the semantic purposes of buttons and radio buttons. There is a difference between them for a reason. Following you guys' logic, we could all start using tables for our lay-out, because it is often easier to position. I don't think that "UI frameworks use this as well" is proving anything, either. Yes, they do it, but I don't think it is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more simple version of scdavis41's answer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#shape > .shapeSelect').click(function(){
    $('#shape > .shapeSelect').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

I also put a selector that includes the control's main div id in case you want to put this control more then once in your page.

** EDIT **

If you absolutly want to use javascript and DOM try this:

```
document.getElementById("square").addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var divArray = document.getElementById("shape").getElementsByTagName("div"); //Get all the div child element of the main div

    for (i = 0, count = divArray.length; i < count; i++) {
        if(divArray[i].getAttribute("class").indexOf("selected") !== -1) { //check if the selected class is contained in the attribute
            divArray[i].setAttribute("class", divArray[i].getAttribute("class").replace("selected", "")); // clear the selected class from the attribute
        }
    };

    document.getElementById("square").setAttribute("class", document.getElementById("square").getAttribute("class").concat(" selected")); //select the square
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is verbose, but you could use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#square').click(function(){
    $('.shapeSelect').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
  $('#circle').click(function(){
    $('.shapeSelect').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
  $('#rounded').click(function(){
    $('.shapeSelect').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

This is [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which means you have to load the jQuery library, but putting this above your script tag:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That gets me a lot closer! I'll try to go and figure out how jQuery does it so i can practice in Javascript.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a pure JavaScript solution, you could try this:

```
if(option == 'add'){
    element.className = element.className + ' selected';
    element.onclick = function() {select(this.id, 'remove')};
    element.innerHTML = '&#10003;';
}
else if(option == 'remove'){
    element.className = element.className.replace(/\bselected\b/,'');
    element.onclick = function() {select(this.id, 'add')};
    element.innerHTML = '';
}
```

JSFiddle: [`http://jsfiddle.net/hKePD/`](http://jsfiddle.net/hKePD/)

**EDIT**

Or if you were looking for a checkbox to be always checked, you could try this: [`http://jsfiddle.net/hKePD/1/`](http://jsfiddle.net/hKePD/1/)

Comment: I have already completed it with PLT's answer. However yours did work and seemed very easy to use. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Building on scadvis41's answer, this is much shorter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('.shapeSelect').click(function(){
    $('.shapeSelect').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

Comment: While that would work I'm trying to stick to javascript just so i can practice. Thank you though!